# Missing number, treated as zero, when attempting figure insertion

Tags: numbering

for some reason, of all my figures, this does not appear to want to be inserted. It keeps giving:

```
"Missing number, treated as zero." <to be read again>
}
\begin{figure}{h}{\textwidth}
```

Where did I go wrong?

Thanks for the help guys!

```
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[11pt]{article} % Default font size is 12pt, it can be changed here

\usepackage{geometry} % Required to change the page size to A4
\geometry{a4paper} % Set the page size to be A4 as opposed to the default US Letter

\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for including pictures

\usepackage{float} % Allows putting an [H] in \begin{figure} to specify the exact location of the figure
\usepackage{wrapfig} % Allows in-line images such as the example fish picture

\usepackage{lipsum} % Used for inserting dummy 'Lorem ipsum' text into the template

\linespread{1.2} % Line spacing

%\setlength\parindent{0pt} % Uncomment to remove all indentation from paragraphs
\usepackage{enumitem}
\graphicspath{{Pictures/}} % Specifies the directory where pictures are stored
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{sidecap}
\usepackage[font=small]{caption}
\begin{document}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{titlepage}

\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}} % Defines a new command for the horizontal lines, change thickness here

\center % Center everything on the page

\textsc{\School}\\[1.5cm] % Name of your university/college
\textsc{\Large Virology}\\[0.5cm] % Major heading such as course name
\textsc{\large Encephalophitides}\\[0.5cm] % Minor heading such as course title

\HRule \\[0.4cm]
{ \huge \bfseries Rabies Virus}\\[0.4cm] % Title of your document
\HRule \\[1.5cm]

\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{flushleft} \large
\emph{Author:}\\
Name \textsc{Name} % Your name
\end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
~
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{flushright} \large
\emph{Supervisor:} \\
Dr. Hi \textsc{Hilles} % Supervisor's Name
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}\\[4cm]

{\large December 4, 2015}\\[3cm] % Date, change the \today to a set date if you want to be precise

%\includegraphics{Logo}\\[1cm] % Include a department/university logo - this will require the graphicx package

\vfill % Fill the rest of the page with whitespace

\end{titlepage}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TABLE OF CONTENTS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\tableofcontents % Include a table of contents

\newpage % Begins the essay on a new page instead of on the same page as the table of contents 



\begin{figure}{h}{\textwidth} 
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{rabiespathology}
  \end{center}
  \caption{Rabies pathogenesis. \cite{Rabiesdiagnosis}}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: `\textwidth` is no macro to be called this way and `figure` has only an optional argument not `{\textwidth}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Not an independent answer, but an elaboration on @ChristianHupfer's answer.)

Here are some of the "doubtful settings" alluded to in Christian Hupfer's answer, listed in no particular order:

- Excessive use of `\\[<length>]]` throughout the `titlepage` environment to generate line breaks and extra vertical spacing. Get rid of these instructions and use, *on a separate line*, `\vspace{<length>}`. Among other things, using `\vspace` you will succeed in placing the horizontal rules symmetrically about the title. (Currently, the lines are placed rather asymmetrically.)
- The command `\center` in the `titlepage` environment should be replaced with `\centering`.
- The macro `\School` isn't defined in your code.
- Don't use the low-level command `\linespread`. It's better to load the `setspace` package and to execute `\setstretch{1.2}` in the preamble.
- When changing font sizes for a single line, be sure to end the line with `\par` in order to get the fontsize-appropriate amount of vertical whitespace below the line.
- If the `minipage` environments don't have equal numbers of rows, be sure to specify the `[t]` alignment specifier so that they will be aligned properly relative to each other.
- In case your document will have a List of Figures, provide a "short version" of the caption that omits the citation call-out.
- Already mentioned by Christian: The `figure` environment does *not* take a width argument; and, you should use `\centering` instead of `\begin{center}` and `\end{center}` *inside* the `figure` environment.
- The default font size in the `article` document class is `10pt`, not `12pt`.

---

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article} %% Default font size is 10pt (*not* 12pt)

\usepackage{geometry} 

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} %% Omit "demo" option in real document
\graphicspath{{Pictures/}}

\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{wrapfig}

%%\linespread{1.2} % Line spacing
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.2}

%\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{sidecap}
\usepackage[font=small]{caption}
\begin{document}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{titlepage}

\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}

%\center % Center everything on the pagen
\centering

%%\textsc{\School} % Name of your university/college
{\Huge\scshape School Name Here}

\vspace{1.5cm}

{\Large\scshape Virology\par} % Major heading, such as course name

\vspace{0.5cm} 

{\large\scshape Encephalophitides\par} % Minor heading, such as course title

\vspace{0.5cm} 

\HRule 

\vspace{0.4cm}

{\huge \bfseries Rabies Virus\par} % Title of document

\vspace{0.4cm} 

\HRule 

\vspace{1.5cm}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{flushleft} \large
\emph{Author:}\\
Name {\scshape Name} % Your name
\end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
~
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
\large
\begin{flushright} 
\emph{Supervisor:} \\
Dr.\ Hi \textsc{Hilles} % Supervisor's Name
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}

\vspace{4cm}

{\large December 4, 2015} % Date, change "\today" to a set hard-coded date

\vspace{3cm}

%\includegraphics{Logo}\\[1cm] % Include a department/university logo

%%\vfill % Fill the rest of the page with whitespace

\end{titlepage}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TABLE OF CONTENTS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\tableofcontents % Include a table of contents

\listoffigures %% Provide a list of figures

\newpage % Begins the essay on a new page instead of on the same page as the table of contents 



\begin{figure}[h!]%{h} %%%{\textwidth} 
  %%\begin{center}
  \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{rabiespathology}
  %%\end{center}
  \caption[Rabies pathogenesis]{Rabies pathogenesis. \cite{Rabiesdiagnosis}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very elaborate where I was too lazy ;-) By the way: The OP hat `11pt`, not `12pt` ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - The fontsize-related comment was directed at the *comment*, in the OP's code, that "Default font size is 12pt, it can be changed here". I thought it was worth setting the record straight, if for no other reason than helping out future readers of this posting...

Answer (score 3):

`\begin{figure}[h]{\textwidth}` is wrong for two reasons:

1. `figure` does not have a mandatory argument, `{\textwidth}` is useless
2. `\textwidth` is a dimension register and cannot used this way. Dimension registers can be assigned to other lengths but the value has to be typeset with `\the\textwidth`.

There are other doubtful settings, but that does not cause the document compilation to fail!

---

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} % Default font size is 12pt, it can be changed here

\usepackage{geometry} % Required to change the page size to A4
\geometry{a4paper} % Set the page size to be A4 as opposed to the default US Letter

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % Required for including pictures

\usepackage{float} % Allows putting an [H] in \begin{figure} to specify the exact location of the figure
\usepackage{wrapfig} % Allows in-line images such as the example fish picture

\usepackage{lipsum} % Used for inserting dummy 'Lorem ipsum' text into the template

\linespread{1.2} % Line spacing

%\setlength\parindent{0pt} % Uncomment to remove all indentation from paragraphs
\usepackage{enumitem}
\graphicspath{{Pictures/}} % Specifies the directory where pictures are stored
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{sidecap}
\usepackage[font=small]{caption}
\begin{document}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{titlepage}

\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}} % Defines a new command for the horizontal lines, change thickness here

\center % Center everything on the page

%\textsc{\School}\\[1.5cm] % Name of your university/college
\textsc{\Large Virology}\\[0.5cm] % Major heading such as course name
\textsc{\large Encephalophitides}\\[0.5cm] % Minor heading such as course title

\HRule \\[0.4cm]
{ \huge \bfseries Rabies Virus}\\[0.4cm] % Title of your document
\HRule \\[1.5cm]

\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{flushleft} \large
\emph{Author:}\\
Name \textsc{Name} % Your name
\end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
~
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{flushright} \large
\emph{Supervisor:} \\
Dr. Hi \textsc{Hilles} % Supervisor's Name
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}\\[4cm]

{\large December 4, 2015}\\[3cm] % Date, change the \today to a set date if you want to be precise

%\includegraphics{Logo}\\[1cm] % Include a department/university logo - this will require the graphicx package

\vfill % Fill the rest of the page with whitespace

\end{titlepage}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TABLE OF CONTENTS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\tableofcontents % Include a table of contents

\clearpage



\begin{figure}[h]%{\textwidth} 
   \centering

    \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{rabiespathology}

  \caption{Rabies pathogenesis. \cite{Rabiesdiagnosis}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi Christian, thanks for the help. If you have time, could you point me to or explain the doubtful settings? I'm very new to latex and have been learning from other documents, and templates but I guess I've been doing things wrong.

Comment: @colonelk1: Too many `\\\` statements, `\begin{center}...\end{center}` in a float environment etc. And as I wrote once before: Saying `thank you` is done by upvoting or accepting an answer (which you haven't done yet for the other questions by you :-( )